# How to 'set' object to a particular base class in multiple inheritence?

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance

I'm trying to inherit from two base classes in **C++**, that have same named functions. I want an object of the class to 'belong' to the particular base class, is it possible to do so?

I have tried virtual base class (does not suit my particular case) and also tried using scope resolution operator with failure.

I want to do this just by using a single class if it's possible.

I have provide the code;

```
#include <SFML\Graphics.hpp>

class entity :public sf::CircleShape, public sf::RectangleShape {
public: 
    entity(int radius = 0) { setRadius(radius); }
    entity(sf::Vector2f size) { setSize(size); }
    float xspeed =0, yspeed =0;
};
```

```
entity ball(6);
entity block(10, 10);
```

```
window.draw(block);   // ambiguity error as both have base class sf::drawable
window.draw(ball);    // and draw function accepts sf::drawable
```

The problem is that I want "ball" just to inherit from `sf::CircleShape` and not from `sf::RectangleShape`.

I expected using scope resolution operator would refer to the `circleshape` class or I might just be using it wrong.

Edit: The problem I'm trying to solve is that I want to draw "ball" and a rectangular block on to the window, and when I try to do that I'm presented with an ambiguity error as they both are drawable (i.e. both `sf::RectangleShape` and `sf::CircleShape` inherit from `sf::drawable`)

Edit(2): [The inheritence diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQzuz.png)

So the function `window.draw();` accepts any object of `sf::drawable` as a parameter. But as I inherit both circleshape and rectangle shape to entity I get an ambiguity error saying `base class is ambiguous`.

I know this is diamond of death situation however using virtual base classes is not possible as they are part of the SFML library and I do not want to modify them

Comment: How can something be both a circle and a rectangle?

Comment: Sorry, C++ does not work this way. This `entity` always inherits from both classes. That's how C++ works. If you want `sf::CircleShape`, then declare your `ball` as `sf::CircleShape`. You can always create a different class that inherits only from `sf::CircleShape`.

Comment: Multiple inheritance isn't like a `union` - inheriting either or. It's inheriting everything. May be, you're looking for a `std::variant`.

Comment: @molbdnilo Fair point. Mathematicians of all times failed to achieve this... ;-)

Comment: Turn it around. Instead of having your entity inherit cirlce and rectangle, have those two inherit entity.

Comment: Both `sf::CircleShape` and `sf::RectangleShape` derive from `sf::Shape`, so maybe you should just make an object of type `sf::Shape` and use polymorphism to decide the type. If you need a "ball", you will create object of type `sf::CircleShape`, and then another object "block" of type `sf::RectangleShape`.

Comment: "The problem is that I want "ball" just to inherit from sf::CircleShape and not from sf::RectangleShape." Then just inherit from `sf:CircleShape`, what's stopping you?

Comment: Basicaly, your question is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please describe the actual problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: @Quimby I said I wanted to solve this by a single class if possible, and now I know it's not

Comment: @AshwinRohit I don't understand the question then.  Please write how you want to use the class including definitions of those base classes.

Comment: @Quimby I have added additional details in the question ask if more required

Comment: @molbdnilo I have inherited from circle and a rectangle as my program requires either a circle or rectangle, so I thought it would be easier if I created a class entity which could refer to them all and by using constructor overloading I could modify their properties

Comment: @Yksisarvinen I have added further details ask me if you want more details

Comment: @Yunnosch Although doing that would solve the problem, I did not want to complicate things by creating new files and adding them to SFML library. I created entity class in my program which inherits from the files in the Library which I have included

Comment: @Scheff I will look into `std::variant` and check if it helps

Comment: @AshwinRohit: "*my program requires either a circle or rectangle*" Then you should use a type which contains either one or the other, not a type which inherits from both.

Comment: @NicolBolas I said I wanted to do with a single class for convenience and I have understood that is not possible

Comment: I seriuosly don't understand your problem. Just use `sf::CircleShape ball(6);
sf::RectangleShape block(10, 10);`. It cannot be simpler than this.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen I have added further details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Problem analysis

> ```
> class entity :public sf::CircleShape, public sf::RectangleShape
> ```

This declaration says that every `entity` is simultaneously a `CircleShape` and a `RectangleShape`. This does not seem to be what you want. You seem to want an entity that can be *either* a circle *or* a rectangle. So this inheritance is not the right strategy.

Given that you are adding horizontal and vertical speeds, it seems like you are trying to add a basic animation to elements that can be drawn. Animation is an abstract concept that builds upon drawing (an animation must be drawn, but not all drawings must be animated). Specific moving shapes would build on top of the animation, so your ideal inheritance would be more like the following:

```
circle -> entity -> drawable
```

However, there are a few drawbacks. One drawback is that this forces all circles to be animated entities, when some circles might simply be drawn in one spot. Plus, the circle and drawable classes are from a library, so you cannot mess with that particular inheritance scheme.

I can think of two reasonable alternatives off the top of my head. *(By the way, "entity" is not a great name for your class, but I'll stick with it for consistency. You should come up with a more descriptive name for the class. It'll be good practice, as naming things is sometimes one of the hardest parts of writing code. :) )*

### Entity as a base class

You could define `entity` as a base class, then define a new class for each shape.

```
             --> sf::CircleShape --> sf::Drawable
            /
MyCircle --<
            \
             --> entity
```

This can work, but it is not great if `entity` needs to invoke functions defined in `Drawable`. Not impossible: a side-cast can make it possible to invoke `Drawable`'s functions. It's just that you then have to account for the case where the side-cast fails, as the compiler cannot catch that.

### Shapes as members

What I would probably do is give up inheritance altogether. Instead of trying to say that your entity is a circle (inheritance), I would go with the approach that your entity has a circle (membership). One benefit of this approach is that it is not hard to extend this to saying that your entity has multiple shapes, all moving at the same speed. I will, though, stick to a single shape for now.

The difficulty with this approach is that you don't know what shape the entity should have -- should it have a circle or a rectangle? Fortunately, this is the sort of thing polymorphism deals with nicely.

```
class entity {
    std::unique_ptr<sf::Drawable> shape; // <-- Polymorphism to the rescue!
    float xspeed = 0.0, yspeed = 0.0;

public:
    // Construct a circle.
    entity(int radius = 0) : shape(std::make_unique<sf::CircleShape>(radius)) {}

    // Construct a rectangle.
    entity(sf::Vector2f size) : shape(std::make_unique<sf::RectangleShape>(size)) {}

    // Something will go here to support drawing.
};
```

To support drawing, there are (at least) two options. If it is appropriate to have an `entity` be a drop-in replacement for a `Drawable`, it might be reasonable to define an implicit conversion.

```
    operator const sf::Drawable &() const { return *shape; }
```

If an implicit conversion is not desirable, marking it `explicit` is an option.

If the only time you need to use an `entity` as a `Drawable` is when you call `window.draw()`, you might want to instead give `entity` a `draw` method that takes `window` as a parameter.

```
    void draw(sf::RenderTarget & target, sf::RenderStates states) const
    { target.draw(*shape, states); }
```

This makes the `Drawable` available to `RenderTarget::draw()` while keeping it out of sight (clutter reduction) at other times.

Answer (score -1):

instead of using inheritance : [image]

simply use direct association :

in your entity class, you want to have RectangleShape and CircleShape , so instead of making the entity class a CircleShape and a RectangeShape at the same time, it's better to consider your entity made of a CircleShape and a RectangleShape .this way you can in your entity class instantiate a RectangeShape and a CircleShape means 'entity' has a Rectangle and a CircleShape

[image]

it's the correct way to do it

Comment: Can you explain further in my scenario

Comment: After including the 2 classes ( Circle and Rectangle ) in the constructor of your entity class you instantuate the 2 shapes : mRectangle = RectangleShape() and mCircle = CircleShape() with the appropriate args .